# Show thumbnail image while larger image is downloading asynchronously in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, uiimageview

I am using [Haneke](https://github.com/Haneke/HanekeSwift) to download and show images asynchronously in CollectionView.
I want to show a smaller thumbnail type of image while the larger image is being downloaded for each cell.

Here's the code:

```
let imageUrl = NSURL(string: "imgUrlString")
let miniImageUrl = NSURL(string: "miniImgUrlString")

func onSuccess(image: UIImage?) {
    cell!.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(imageUrl!)
}
cell!.imageView.hnk_setImageFromURL(miniImageUrl!, placeholder: nil, format: nil, failure: onFailure, success: onSuccess)
```

Also there is preloader image set on ImageView of Cell just after dequeing it.

```
cell?.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "preloader")
```

**The Problem**

The `onSuccess` handler is called, but the mini image is never visible. The image changes from "preloader" to "image", while I want the mini image to load soon and then change to original image.
What am I missing?

Comment: check if imgUrlString and miniImgString are not same?

Comment: @SaurabhPrajapati: I have checked it, separately they are showing up the right images.
If I don't write a `onSuccess`, the correct thumbnail image shows up.

Comment: @Larme: coz I want to show "preloader" image as soon as cell appears, but I don't think changing it would solve the problem.